HybridBodies name is read only
I'm facing a problem while developping a vba macro for CATIA V5.
I want to create, rename and fill few geometrical sets in a CATPart file.
I'm able to create a new set, but when I try to change its name as shown in forums or tutorials (set.name = "newname"), I get the following error : Compilation Error : Impossible to change a read only property
Do you know what happens ?
Here is my code :
Set oDocument = catia.ActiveDocument
Set myPart = oDocument.Part
Set objHSF = myPart.HybridShapeFactory
Set GeometryFromExcel = oDocument.Part.HybridBodies.Item("GeometryFromExcel") ' Récupérer le set géométrique contenant l'ensemble des informations de mesure

Set objRef = myPart.CreateReferenceFromObject(GeometryFromExcel) ' Pointer le set
objHSF.DeleteObjectForDatum objRef ' Supprimer le set
    
Debug.Print ">>> MAJ du set de points ..."
Dim NewGeometryFromExcel As HybridBodies
Set NewGeometryFromExcel = myPart.HybridBodies.Add()
Debug.Print NewGeometryFromExcel.Name


NewGeometryFromExcel.Name = "lala"

I tried to put Set before NewGeometryFromExcel.Name = "lala" and I got a new error : Compilation Error : Bad use of the property

The error message *Impossible to change a read only property" says it: Seems that the name property is read only - you cannot change it. Using Set is wrong, it is used to assign object references, but name is (most likely, I don't have any Catia documentation) a String.

NewGeometryFromExcel should be dimensioned as HybridBody

Thanks Shrotter, using Dim As HybridBody (singular) worked very well
